# How to pass vuejs element instance by reference

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Ok it looks like its a really simple question, but i can't figure it out. I have a vuejs project in which i have this component code:

```
   <div>
     <v-chip @click="chip_active(// pass the reference //)" 
     color="#E0E0E0" class="white--text" 
     v-for="single_interest in interest" :key="single_interest">
     {{ single_interest }}
     </v-chip>
   </div>
```

So in the click method i need to change the property color of one single instance of the chip element (the one clicked), not the hole v-for chips.
To do this i thought of passing the chip instance reference and change the property color directly from the method, the problem is that i don't know how to do this on vuejs.
Anyone who can help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So i would approach this like this, keeps the concerns more separate

- on each of the chips, have a `selected` that is false by default
- add an `@click=setSelected(chip)`
- in your setSelected, set the value of the one selected to be true and the others to be false

If you don't want to set a value on the chips you could also keep a completely separate variable that is `selectedChip` that holds the value of the selected chip.  You setSelected would then change the value of selectedChip.  You would also need to pass `selectedChip` into your loop so that you can handle the display if the current chip is selected

Comment: Hey, do you know how to access the property list of an element using $event.target, i could not find this anywhere.

Comment: Hey, any chance that you could setup a fiddle with specifically what you are running into?  What specific thing is causing you to need to access the target?